# findAll() method does not return recently inserted record when OneToOne relationship mapped with MapsId

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have 2 entity class named Post and PostDetails. Both are mapped with OneToOne relationship using `MapsId` and sharing the primary key as shown below.

**Post.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
@Data
public class Post implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6698422774799518217L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NaturalId
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "post", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private PostDetail detail;

}
```

**PostDetail.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "post_detail")
@Data
public class PostDetail implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6699482774799518217L;

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "created_on")
    private Date createdOn;

    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String createdBy;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Post post;

}
```

**PostController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/post")
public class PostController
{
    private final PostRepository postRepository;

    private final PostDetailRepository postDetailRepository;

    public PostController(PostRepository postRepository, PostDetailRepository postDetailRepository)
    {
        this.postRepository = postRepository;
        this.postDetailRepository = postDetailRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/create")
    public List<Post> createAndGetPosts()
    {

        Post post=new Post();
        post.setId(new Random().nextLong());
        post.setTitle("First Post");
        post=postRepository.saveAndFlush(post);

        PostDetail postDetail =new PostDetail();
        postDetail.setCreatedBy("Admin");
        postDetail.setCreatedOn(Date.from(Instant.now()));
        postDetail.setPost(post);
        postDetailRepository.saveAndFlush(postDetail);

        return postRepository.findAll(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC,"id"));
    }


}
```

In Post Controller class I create Post object (save it DB) and then pass it to PostDetail object then save it to database using Spring Data JPA. Everything works as expected. But when I fetch list of records immediately, through `postRepository.findAll(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC,"id"));` method I receive `null` value for PostDetail object inside Post as shown below.

**Response:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "First Post",
    "detail": null
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Post1",
    "detail": {
      "id": 1,
      "createdOn": "2019-06-21T03:31:43.000+0000",
      "createdBy": "Admin"
    }
  }
]
```

But when I send request again from frontend for the list, I get proper response. I tried to put flush statement and second findAll() statement before the request, nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you receive exactly same instance that was returned from `saveAndFlush` and stored in `post` variable.

Hibernate doesn't update `Post.detail` when you do `postDetail.setPost(post)`.

To fix it you can set `detail` manually or evict `Post` instance from cache after save which force hibernate to reload it from DB.

Comment: 1. I am not using any caching solution, even then `findAll()` evicts everything from and loads data again

Comment: Are you use stateless session in hibernate? If not hibernate have session cache. `findAll` doesn't evict anything. It indeed load data from DB, then lookup instances in session cache by id and create new only if it id absent in cache.

Comment: Do you know any option to evict Post instance from cache and force findAll load from DB? At present I am setting `PostDetail` object manually and looking for simpler option

Comment: You need to inject `org.hibernate.Session` and call `evict` after save. But I think it will be simpler to just call `post.setDetail(postDetail)` after save and change `postDetailRepository.saveAndFlush(postDetail)` to `postDetail = postDetailRepository.saveAndFlush(postDetail)`.